# To show that $y$ is the best approximation of $x$ from $G$ i.e $y$ is the unique element of $G$ such that $||x-y||=d(x,G)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert Space $H$. For $x \in H$, let $y$ be the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $G$. Then I need to show that $y$ is the best approximation of $x$ from $G$  i.e $y$ is the unique element of $G$ such that $||x-y||=d(x,G)$

Since $H$ is hilbert space and $G$ is closed, $H=G \oplus G^{\perp}$, $x=g+g'$ uniquely and $<g,g'>=0$.
Now $d(x,G) \le ||x-g||$. Suppose $d(x,G) \lt ||x-g||$. Then there exists a $g_1 \in G$ such that $d(x,G) \lt ||x-g_1|| \lt ||x-g||$. Hence $||x-g_1||^2 \lt ||x-g||^2$ implying that $(<x-g_1,x-g_1>)  \lt  (<x-g,x-g>)$.Thus $$(<x,x>-<x,g_1>-<g_1,x>+<g_1,g_1> )\lt <x,x>-<x,g>-<g,x>+<g,g>$$
Now $<x,g>=<g,g>=<g,x>$. Again $<x,g_1>=<g,g_1>$. Substituting these in the equation we get $$-<g,g_1>- <g_1,g>+||g_1||^2 \lt -||g||^2 \implies ||g-g_1||^2 \lt 0$$

This is a contradiction. The uniqueness follows from the fact that $x$ can be written uniquely

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Not sure if uniqueness follows trivially. You have not proved that if $\|x-y\| = d(x,G)$ then $x-y \in G^{\perp}$. Only if you prove this can you then appeal to uniqueness of the decomposition.

Comment: If $ g_1 \in G$ with $ g_1 \not  =  g$      then     $ ||x-g||^2= ||g^'||^2 < ||g^'||^2+||g-g_1||^2= ||g^'+(g-g_1)||^2  (because  g^' and  g-g_1$are orthogonal). This last expression is equal to  ||x-g_1||^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $y$ is that $y\in G$ and $(x-y)\perp G$. Therefore, if $y' \in  G$
$$
                x-y' = (x-y)+(y-y')
$$
and the decomposition on the right is orthogonal because $y-y' \in G$. So
$$
                  \|x-y'\|^{2}=\|x-y\|^{2}+\|y-y'\|^{2} \ge \|x-y\|^{2},
$$
with equality iff $y=y'$.